# What does dpkg --auto-deconfigure actually do?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to replace Nginx with a version that has the PageSpeed module compiled in, and I've made my own `.deb` file for this. The first step is to uninstall the old `nginx`. However, when I try `apt-get remove nginx-common` I'm told it will install `nginx-full` in the same step. That's not what I want.

If I try `dpkg -i ./my-new-nginx.deb`, that fails because it conflicts with the `nginx-core` currently installed.  Adding `--auto-deconfigure` option to this command looks like it might help. It's documented like this:

> Specifying this option will cause automatic deconfiguration of the package which  depended  on  the removed package.

But "deconfiguration" is not defined. *What does deconfiguration actually do*?

Configuration consists of these steps:

> 1. Unpack  the  conffiles,  and at the same time back up the old conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.
> 2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.

It's not clear what the intended "opposite" results of these steps would be.

Comment: It's fairly clear what the opposite is: Run the `prerm` script, if provided by the package; restore the backed up old conffiles, if they exist; run the `postrm` script, if provided by the package